# Possible to configure webpack "cheap-module-source-map" when webpack config is imported in external npm module?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Our company breaks functionality out into npm modules. All of the webpack config is setup in an npm module we import into our app.

I'm keen to use the *cheap-module-source-map* setting https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html#webpack and was curious if there was any way to make webpack use cheap-module-source-map when I can't modify the webpack.config (modifying the config in the common npm package is a less desirable option because other are using it).

Comment: Copy the npm module directory to your local machine or local network and then modify it as your needs and use this command to install. npm install /path

Comment: Of course! Thanks.